# Using Ajax to load data in <display:table /> Spring 2.5

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

my company use **Spring 2.5**
And i have a task to modify it using Ajax technology. I already try to using ajax to save data :

```
$('#klikDeh').click(function() {
    //alert($('#mtsh').serialize());
    $.ajax({
        url: 'isiulang.spr',
        data: $('#mtsh').serialize(),
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSend:function(){
            $(".loading_msg").show();
        },
        complete:function(){
            $(".loading_msg").hide();
        },
        success: alert($('#mtsh').serialize())
    });
});
```

But, the saved data using `<display:table>` which use the method from Controller Spring.

Here is the method `referenceData` which used to the View to get passed data.

```
protected Map referenceData(HttpServletRequest request, Object command, Errors errors) throws Exception {
        ModelMap map = new ModelMap();

        Validation val = new Validation();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

        String aniDealer = val.getANIFromLoggedInUser(session);
        String[] aniD = {aniDealer};

        EdsWSFE qq = new EdsWSFE();
        EpulseWSFE qq2 = new EpulseWSFE();
        map.put("dealerSalesman", qq.getSalesmanFromANIDealer(aniDealer));
        List<ReportBalance> rb = qq2.getBalance(aniD);

        map.put("userDealer", (rb.size()>0)?rb.get(0):null);

        map.put("transaction",qq2.getLastReport(0, aniDealer, 15));

        map.put("error", request.getParameter("error") == null ? "" : request.getParameter("error"));

        map.put("voucherList", voucherList);

        map.put("voucherSize", voucherList.size());

        return map;
    }
```

And here is `<display:table>` in Application's View

```
<display:table name="transaction" class="list" id="reportlist" requestURI="" export="true" pagesize="15" style="autowrap">
    <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="isiulang.xls" />
    <display:setProperty name="export.csv.filename" value="isiulang.csv" />
    <display:setProperty name="export.xml.filename" value="isiulang.xml" />
    <display:column title="ID TRANS" property="noTrans" sortable="true" style="white-space: normal" />
    <display:column title="TANGGAL"  sortable="true">
        <fmt:formatDate pattern="dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm:ss" value="${reportlist.tanggal}"/>
    </display:column>
    <display:column title="NAMA" property="nama" />
    <display:column title="TRANSAKSI" property="transaksi" />
    <display:column media="html">
        Rp. 
    </display:column>
    <display:column title="JUMLAH"  style="text-align: right">
        <fmt:formatNumber value="${reportlist.jumlah}"/>,-
    </display:column>
    <display:column media="html">
        &nbsp; &nbsp;
    </display:column>
    <display:column media="html">
        &nbsp; &nbsp;
    </display:column>
    <display:column title="KETERANGAN" property="keterangan" />
    <display:column title="STATUS" property="status" />
</display:table>
```

How to combine with ajax to load that data?
Please help, thank you ^^